# Javascript no longer works after form redesign

Tags: javascript, asp.net

We have a piece of javascript injected onto a page that was responsible for a redirect, after a redesign of the page and the master page the javascript no longer works.

The Javascript is exactly as below

```
function PostVspForm()
{{
    var vspForm = document.forms['vsp'];
    if (!vspForm) vspForm = document.vsp;
    if (!vspForm.onsubmit || (vspForm.onsubmit() != false)) 
    {{
        vspForm.action = '{0}';
        vspForm.submit();
    }}
}}
PostVspForm();
```

I'm not confident what it does or how to correct it,  bearing in mind it also needs to work as above as well.

I believe it's simply identifying a form called vsp,  this form is still on the page but now after calling document.vsp the object is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed the location of this code relative to the vsp form that it is targetting? If so, you may be running it before the form exists in the page.

Try moving your js to the bottom of the page, or wrap it in a block like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
  //your code here
  console.log(vspForm);
}
```

If you are using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The js immediately follows the form, really a piece of javascript that will find the form regardless of its location on the page should be enough.

Comment: This has been resolved by moving the form outside of the body of another form. The redesign changed the layout a lot and I guess you can't have form tags inside form tags without updating that javascript. I moved the form instead and left the script the same.

Comment: Nice, glad you got it worked out. I recently had an accidental form inside form issue and the browser didn't render the inner form at all since it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. Using Javascript for redirection or some sort of validation. I would recommend replacing it by a code behind located in the page_load() method.

Comment: Javascript is great for validating input before a round trip to the server.

Comment: Oh yes of course, but it's surely not a definitive validation method.